# SignalR only Working 50% of the time when consuming event from RabbitMQ

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, masstransit, azure-service-fabric

I've noticed a bug in my application where every **other** message in my signalr hub makes it to my client (angular 4).  The hub method is called when a message from RabbitMQ is consumed (through MassTransit abstraction).  It is repeatedly reproducible, with no variations.

In the same hub, there are other methods that are called that don't have a RabbitMQ origin (service fabric actor events, etc).  All of these reliable make it to the client 100% of the time.  Therefore, it seems like the issue has something to do with RabbitMQ and MassTransit.

The issue happens between the *Clients.All.MyMethod(stuff)* call and the client.  There are absolutely no errors being logged, and nothing to indicate a problem other than the message not being handled by the client.  On all other methods, the logging from signalR would show.

Any ideas what may be the problem?

Notes:  Using SignalR 2, ASP Net Core 2.0, Service Fabric, MassTransit RabbitMq 3.4.1, Angular 4

Comment: Just a suggestion but check you haven't got a competing consumer for the message. It has happened to me before when I have forgotten to remove an older version of a consumer. Check in your bus config.

Comment: Ended up being a competing consumer; occurring due to having two web listeners (http, and https).  Cheers @robs!